# how to get amount value in kb of data used by internet?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

i making a application where i need total amount of data used by user by accessing internet.
how could i get that value.
plz help me send the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no APIs to directly get the amount of data used in KB.

The methods that come closest are

`net.rim.device.api.system.RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived()`  and

```
net.rim.device.api.system.RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent()
```

These give you the number of IP packets sent/received.  MTU (Maximum Transmission Unit) for a packet over a cellular radio is usually around 600-1200 bytes, so you can get an approximation, but individual packets may differ by a few hundred bytes, so you can't get an exact amount.  Depending on your app, this may be enough.

Comment: thnks alot..
how to listen for whenever internet is statting or ending.